# I want to find the sum of this two tables

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to find the sum of this two tables

Please help me to fix this issue

## Table 1

```
id  |  pr_id  |  cl_one
========================
 1  |    2    |   500
------------------------
 2  |    2    |   500
```

## Table 2

```
id  |  pr_id  |   cl2
======================
 1  |    2    |   500
```

## codeigniter query

```
$this->db->select('SUM(s.cl_one)+SUM(l.cl2) AS total_amount, COUNT(s.cl_one)+SUM(l.cl2) AS total_counts')
                      ->from('Table1 AS s')
                      ->join('Table2 AS l', 's.pr_id = l.pr_id')
                      ->get()->row();
```

## Result

```
total_amount = 2000;

total_counts = 4;
```

## I need a result like this

```
total_amount = 1500;

total_count = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting 2000 because when you join one row in table2, to two rows in table1, the single row from t2 duplicates itself to match up to the two rows from t1. If you then sum the duplicated row you've added in an extra 500

The easiest way to resolve these things is to group and sum them before you join them:

```
SELECT t1.sum + t2.sum as total
FROM
  (SELECT pr_id, sum(cl_one) as sum FROM table1 GROUP BY pr_id) t1    
  INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT pr_id, sum(cl_2) as sum FROM table2 GROUP BY pr_id) t2    
  ON t1.pr_id = t2.pr_id
```

This way one row from t1 matches one row from t2, no duplicating...
But I've no idea how you'd do this in codeigniter/whatever ORM you're using, but I hope this can help/be easily translated

Comment: But, if the table 2 is empty ?

Comment: Things get more tricky then; the Union you have is probably the simplest way to resolve it. A full outer join can do it too but it's awkward in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

**Finally made it...**

**A simple query to fix this**

```
SELECT pr_id, SUM(sum_v) AS total_amount, COUNT(sum_v) AS total_counts FROM( 
SELECT pr_id, cl_one AS sum_v FROM table1  UNION ALL 
SELECT pr_id, cl2 AS sum_v FROM table2)x GROUP BY pr_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter query:

```
$res1 = $this->db->select('SUM(cl_one) as total, COUNT(cl_one) as count').from('Table1').get().row();
$res2 = $this->db->select('SUM(cl_2) as total, COUNT(cl_2) as count').from('Table2').get().row();
$total_amount = $res1[0]['total'] + $res2[0]['total'];
$total_count = $res1[0]['count'] + $res2[0]['count'];
```